# How to properly add custom animation to fragment transactions in android? (screen size independent)

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, screen-size, objectanimator

I am trying to animate fragment transactions in my activity so new fragment slides in upwards and old slides out upwards, I have only managed to make it work for a specific display height. Here is my code:

.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <objectAnimator             
         android:duration="400"
         android:propertyName="y"
         android:valueFrom="1000"
         android:valueTo="0"
         android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

and

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <objectAnimator       
        android:duration="400"
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

java:

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, mNewFragment);
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This works perfectly fine in a smartphone with a medium resolution, but if I use a device with a larger screen size the animations will not be displayed properly since the slide distances will not be large enough, vice versa, if I hardcode a larger size in my xml I get a blank space between fragments as they slide.

I need a way to set the 'android:valueFrom="1000"' and 'android:valueTo="0"' according to the device´s screen size so i end up with 'android:valueFrom="display_height"'.

What would be the best approach to solve this? would you give me an example?

facts:
xml

android:valueFrom="100%" //cannot be used as value for the property

android:valueFrom="%1$d" //variables cannot be used as value for the property

java

ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menuFragmentContainer, "y", 1000, 0); //I am not sure how to use the programmatic way

Comment: You should use percent instead of pixels in your animations.

Answer (score -2):

Try using a translate animation. Something like this should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

Then just change the values of `YDelta` to whatever you need

Put this file under res/animator and call it the same way you call your previous animations

Comment: This only works with support fragments and then needs to be in anim.